# jQuery dynamically added elements cannot be removed

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I have been trying to work out a solution to this issue, and have come across many similar posts online,.. but none with solutions that worked for my particular instance.

I'm using jQuery it 'inserAfter' within a group of elements. I can add the groups easily,.. but, I also have a remove() function called when a delete link is clicked,.. but nothing happens to the newly added elements, even though I can delete the other groups without problems.

I'm using jQuery's on() for the click function.. but, that still doesn't work on the dynamically added elements.

To reproduce the issue, go to the jsfiddle link below,
Click the ADD GROUP button and see a yellow group added to the DOM.
Now, hover over the yellow group to show the delete button.
Click the delete button and, tada... nothin'

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/revive/5MFRm/

```
jQuery(function($) { 

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $("#group0").hide();
    $('.group-content').hide(); // Hide all group-content elements

    function clonePanel() {          
        var panel=$("#tabs #group0").clone(false),
            lastpanel = $("#tabs .group").last().index(),
            newid = 'group'+(lastpanel+1);

        panel.attr('id',newid).addClass('newpanel'); 
        panel.insertAfter($("#tabs .group").last()).show();
    }                 

    $(".add-group").on('click',function(){  
        clonePanel();    
    });

    $(".delete-group").on('click',function(){  
        $(this).closest('.group').fadeOut('slow', function(){$(this).closest('.group').remove(); }); 
    //          alert('done');
    });  

    $('#tabs').on('click', '.group-title-toggle',function(){ // Add class "hover" on dt when hover
        $(this).closest('.group-title').toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle(); // Toggle dd when the respective dt is clicked
    }); 

});
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times on SO. Did you try searching for "jquery on dynamic doesn't work" ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my comment in the question itself. And none of them applied to my code - they all essentially said 'Use, live() for the older posts, and use on() for the newer ones.. I already am.. is this why you down voted my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what you are looking for: [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements).

And here is your code working properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/5MFRm/2/

Instead of `$('.add-group').on('click', function() {})`

use this notation

`$('body').on('click', '.add-group', function() {})`

Comment: Unfortunately, that is already a syntax I have tried.. but that doesn't work either.. see here http://jsfiddle.net/revive/5MFRm/3/

Comment: Add quote (') to your body selector ... like this $('body')

Comment: #FACEPALM !!!  Ah, man.. can't believe I missed that.. I know better.. Thanks Felipe !!

Answer (score 0):

Please use [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It will listen for all objects created in the future .

Comment: live was removed with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Right, 'on' can help. There are examples on the link I've posted.

Comment: Yeah, live() is deprecated. That is why I'm using on. @Andron, I AM using on().. that's why I've posted the question.. it's still not working LOL