# Removing jQuery dynamically added elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Have looked at several other questions on this [Handeling dynamically added elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480962/handeling-dynamically-added-elements-with-jquery) [jQuery dynamically added elements cannot be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344311/jquery-dynamically-added-elements-cannot-be-removed), but none of them seem to answer the specific problem I have been encountering. I am adding an input text field and a paragraph element dynamically when a user clicks on a button already present in the DOM "#passwordEditButton". This works fine , however, I am unable to then remove the newly added element when the user clicks the same button. I can only guess that changing the img element that acts as a button dynamically removes it from the DOM and hence it does not respond to remove() - please help how do I solve this!?

```
<div class="main-wrapper grouping">
   <section  class="select grouping">

     <div class="button-wrapper grouping">
           <div class="button-select"><a href="uploads.php">My uploads</a></div>
            <div class="button-select"><a href="settings.php">My settings</a></div>
           <div class="button-select current"><a href="account.php">My account</a></div>
           <div class="button-select"><a href="ratings.php">My ratings</a></div>
     </div>

   </section> 


   <section class="information grouping">
    <div class="details"">

     <h2>My Account Information </h2>

     <img  id="mainEditButton" src="../images/edit2.png">         



   <div id="wrapper-account">

     <div class="tablerow">
      <p>First name:</p> 
          <p><input class="inputBox" type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>"></p>

     </div>

      <div class="tablerow">

        <p>Last name:</p>
        <p><input class="inputBox"  type="text" name="lastName" value="   <?php echo $lastName; ?>"></p>

    </div>

      <div class="tablerow">

       <p> School address:</p>
       <p><input class="inputBox " type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"></p>

     </div>

      <div class="tablerow">

       <p>School city:</p>
       <p><input class="inputBox" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>"></p>

      </div>

      <div class="tablerow">

       <p>School zip:</p>
       <p><input class="inputBox " type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>"></p>

      </div>

     <div class="tablerow">

      <p>School telephone:</p>
      <p><input class="inputBox" type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>"></p>

     </div>

     <div class="tablerow">

      <p>School email:</p>  
      <p> <input class="inputBox" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>

     </div>


    <div class="wrapper-upload" >
      <p>Qualification: <input type="file"  name="qualification" class="files"></p>
     </div>

    </div>  

   </div> 



   <div class="details password">


   <img id="passwordEditButton" src="../images/edit2.png">

   <div class="tablerow username-div">

        <p>Username:</p>
        <p><input id="username" class="password-box" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" ></p>

    </div>
     <div class="tablerow password-div">

        <p>Password:</p>
        <p><input  id="passwordOrignal" class="password-box" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" ></p>

    </div>

    <div id="placeholderUsername"></div>
     <div id="placeholderNewPassword"></div>
      <div id="placeholderConfirmPassword"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="membership-details">
 <p>Joined on: </p>
 <p>Membership Status: </p>
 <p>Current rating:<?php echo $points; ?> </p>
 </div>

 </div>     

    <script>




   $(document).ready(function() {





     $("#passwordEditButton").click(function () {

     $(this).toggleClass("selected");

     if($( "#passwordEditButton" ).hasClass( "selected" )) {

      $("#passwordEditButton").attr('src', '../images/editing.png');






        $('#placeholderUsername').append('<div>    </div>').addClass("tablerow username-div");
         $('.username-div').attr("id","usernameDiv");
          $('#usernameDiv').append('<p>New Username</p>');
           $('#usernameDiv').append('<p></p>').attr("id","newUser");
            $('#newUser').append('<input>').addClass("password-Box").attr( { id:"newUsername", type:"text", name:"newUsername", value:" " } );


          $('.details.password').append('<div></div>').attr("id","newPasswordDiv");
            $('#newPasswordDiv').append('<p>New Password</p>');
             $('#newPasswordDiv').append('<p></p>').attr("id","newPassword");
              $('#newPassword').append('<input>').addClass("password-Box").attr( { id:"enterNewPassword", type:"password", name:"enterNewPassword", value:" " } );


            $('.details.password').append('<div> </div>').attr("id","confirmPasswordDiv");
              $('#confirmPasswordDiv').append('<p>Confirm Password</p>');
               $('#confirmPasswordDiv').append('<p> </p>').attr("id","confirmPassword");
                $('#confirmPassword').append('<input>').addClass("password-Box").attr( { id:"confirmNewPassword", type:"password", name:"confirmNewPassword", value:" " } );




      $("input.password-Box").toggleClass('errorBoxPassword');


        $(".details.password").css({"height":"280px"});
         $(".details.password").css({"bottom":"0px"});
          $("#username").css({"position":"absolute"});
           $("#username").css({"top":"10px"});
            $("#username").css({"left":"98px"}); 


      } 
      else 
      { 
        $("#passwordEditButton").attr('src', '../images/edit2.png');

        $("#username").css({"position":"static"}); 


      $('#placeholderUsername').empty();

     //none of these work
      $('#usernameDiv').closest.remove();
       $('#newPasswordDiv').remove();
        $('#confirmPasswordDiv').parent().remove();
         $('input.password-Box').toggleClass('errorBoxPassword');
          $('.details.password').css({"height":"auto"});
           $('.details.password').css({"bottom":"30px"});


      }
       });

      $("#mainEditButton").click(function () {

      if(mainEditing == false) {

      $("#mainEditButton").attr('src', '../images/editing.png');
      mainEditing=true;
        $("input.inputBox").toggleClass('errorBox');



      }else 
      {

       $("#mainEditButton").attr('src', '../images/edit2.png');
       mainEditing=false;
       $("input.inputBox").toggleClass('errorBox');
      }

      });

     });



   </script>






  </div>

  </div>
     <footer>
         <p>Website design and coding provided by Technology in Learning 2016 Copyright Technology in Learning</p> 
         <img  src="../images/company.png" height="12"  width="12"> 
     </footer>

<?php
}
 ?>
```

Comment: If you can create a snippet or fiddle then it would be easy to find out your issue.

Comment: you can use `.toggle()` function with particular element for display it or hide.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is interspersed with PHP and I am not sure fiddle can handle that as I did not see a PHP box

Comment: Go to browsers url and get the content from your html source and then paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

to empty div container content use

```
 $('.details.password').html("")
```

Comment: according to the code he already has some elements in .details.password, so if he uses above code it will remove his existing elements too.. don't you think??

Comment: he could have, right, but i didn't see any information about it.

Comment: this is true. I have some non dynamically added elements inside that div container already. I want too remove the dynamically added ones only by individual id

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
$('.username-div').remove();
```

And if `username-div` are multiple and you want to delete the last one then use [:last-selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) like,

```
$('.username-div:last').remove();
```

Comment: Neither of these methods remove dynamically created elements - I have tried this approach already, but thanks for the response.

Comment: If you want to delete that div on `else` part of `passwordEditButton` button click then definitely it will work. If not, then create a snippet or fiddle so that I can help you in finding your problem.